# ArcGIS API maximum distance in feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, distance, feature-layer

I use ArcGIS API of JavaScript to show a feature on the map. I use FeatureLayer and set definition Expression but I want to show results with maximum distance, for example show to use only the feature with distance between feature and one specified point is value.

Comment: I have 2 ways in my mind, but the first don't work I don't know why 
1/
 create a javascript Function who calculate the distance between two points and call this function in the expression " this method don't work I don't know why" 
2/
 if exist a defined method in arcGis to do this??

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.